# Dynamic DIV for 2 different views

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a dynamic DIV using CSS and angular. Here is what I have so far:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3126/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'views';


}
```

I have the big DIV (marked with red). In this DIV I have 2 DIVs: the left one (black) and the right one (yellow). And 2 links: 7 days and 30 days. When I click on 7 days I should have the first view: here i have the right div with a fix width and  the left one who has to adjust his width ("red div" minus "yellow  div").

When I click on 30 days link, the yellow DIV should disappear and the black div should be as big as the red one.

So far I managed to make the right div appear and disappear.. The problem is with the left one who is not expanding for none of the views

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D94QB/)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3140/. It represents how to do "Take full width when this condition is verified".

`ng-class="{w100: show_tab==2}"` means "the `w100` class will be applied to the element if `show_tab==2` is true".

Some remarks for you:

- In CSS, `#child_element_id` is enough for an id definition. You **should not** define a selector as follows: `some_selector #child_element_id {...}`
- The floating element should be placed first, that's why the `#unu_doi` comes before `#unu_unu`

Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome, but please not the difference between the solutions: callmekatootie' makes `unu_unu` having full width even when `show_tab!=2`. Mine will adapt the size accordingly. At least, you've got the choice! ;)